# Show facebook friends activities from my site

Tags: 6, social-network

I have connected Facebook on my Drupal site. My requirements are as follows.

Suppose user X log in using Facebook. He does different sorts of activities like creates an order, writes a review, likes a content etc.

When another user Y logs in to my site through fbconnect, I have to show him his friends' activities on my site. For example, in this case if X and Y are friends in Facebook, Y needs to see all of X's activities in my site.

How can I achieve this feature? I'm using Drupal 6.

Comment: i am using drupal 6, now i found a way to achieve this by using'drupal for facebook' module and some custom codes.

Comment: If you found the solution, please post it as an answer so that others can benefit from it in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Drupal for Facebook module, it provides a views filter 'Friend of current user'.
 For showing various activities, 'Activity' module used. Then with help of view the friends activities filtered.